# cannot change observable from try catch block in mobx strict mode

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

```
class Someclass {
  @observable waiting = false;
  @observable error = null;

  @action.bound
  async authenticate({login, password}) {
    try {
      this.waiting = true;
      const res = await myService.authenticate(login, password);
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error; // Gives an error: Invariant Failed
    } finally {
      this.waiting = false; // Gives an error: Invariant Failed

      // I've tried doing this too
      // action(() => {
      //   this.waiting = false;
      // })
    }
  }


}
```

In above example altering values from catch and finally block gives an error or warning **Invariant Failed** with strict mode. What is the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `async` function we must wrap a function inside `runInAction` utility method for mutating `@observable` in `strict` mode. Example.

```
class Someclass {
  @observable waiting = false;
  @observable error = null;

  @action.bound
  async authenticate({login, password}) {
    try {
      this.waiting = true;
      const res = await myService.authenticate(login, password);
    } catch (error) {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.error = error;
      });
    } finally {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.waiting = false;
      });
    }
  }


}
```

[View this related issue on github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/299)